# Svelte not printing array elements after they're edited

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

Hey I've got this issue while learning svelte, I made this todo app with my simple knowledge in svelte.
The problem is I add todos, they get added. I delete todos and they get deleted. But, when I delete multiple todos and try to insert a new todo it doesn't print the todo to the HTML and it gives an error saying:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')

CODE:

```
<script>


  let todos = []
  let heading = 'Enter heading here';
  let msg = 'enter your todo here'
  let n = 1;
  function pushTodo(){
    todos = [...todos, new Todo(n, heading, msg)]
    n+=1
        // Logged todos and n for debugging purposes
        console.log('added todo and increased n to'+ n)
        console.log(todos)
  }

  class Todo{
    constructor(id, title, msg){
      this.id = id
      this.title = title
      this.msg = msg
    }
  }

  function deleteTodo(id) {
    todos.splice(id-1, 1);
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
        // Logged the todo array for debugging purposes
    console.log(todos)
  }
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={heading}>
<input type="text" bind:value={msg}>

<button on:click={pushTodo}>insert todo</button>

{#each todos as {id, title, msg}}
<div id= {id.toString()}>
<h6>{id}</h6>
<h2>{title}</h2>
<h4>{msg}</h4>
<button on:click={()=>{deleteTodo(id)}}>delete</button>
</div>
 
{/each}
```

Comment: The input has a placeholder attribute for the instructions what to write https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be removing HTML elements yourself, svelte does that for you. The problem is, when you call `todos.splice`, svelte won't realize that the content of `todos` has changed. You need to assign to `todos` to achieve that. Try this:

```js
  function deleteTodo(id) {
    // find the index of the element to remove
    const index = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    // important: assign todos to itself
    // that way svelte realizes that the content of todos has changed!
    todos = todos;
        // Logged the todo array for debugging purposes
    console.log(todos)
  }
```

Comment: Or filter `todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);`